# Iterate through images in 2 folders

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have 2 Folders: 1 folder having train-images and others having corresponding masks.

How do I make sure that the image and its corresponding label is taken for training my algorithm.

This is the code to load train images:

```
train_images = []

for directory_path in glob.glob(r"D:\Train"):
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.jpg")):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)       
        img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X))
        train_images.append(img)
```

This is the code to load mask images:

```
train_masks = [] 
for directory_path in glob.glob(r"D:\Mask"):
    for mask_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tiff")):
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, 0)       
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)  
        train_masks.append(mask)
```

After splittling them for X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

If I do a sanity check to see if the image is matching it's mask, the pair is random.
Code:

```
import random
import numpy as np
image_number = random.randint(0, len(X_train))
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(X_train[image_number], (256, 256)), cmap='gray')
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(np.reshape(y_train[image_number], (256, 256)), cmap='gray')
plt.show()'''
```

How do I rectify this?

Comment: first: you should use similar names for both. Second: you should sort names to make sure they are in the same order. System doesn't have to give filenames in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

System doesn't have to give filenames in alphabetical order.
You should sort them to make sure you have correct order

```
 for img_path in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.jpg"))):

 for mask_path in sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tiff"))):
```

Of course it needs similar filenames for `jpg` and `tiff` to get the same order.